# Binding an empty texture to image unit produces segfault

Tags: c++, opengl, compute-shader

I want to draw to the texture via a compute shader. For this I am trying to bind the texture to an image unit:

```
    glBindImageTexture(0, texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
```

But when I run the code it produces a segfault.
This is how I create the empty texture:

```
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I used the following tutorial for compute shaders: https://antongerdelan.net/opengl/compute.html

Comment: What exact access violation do you get, and where? Maybe you simply don't have a `glBindImageTexture` function or you screwed up your GL loading in some way.

Comment: Is there a way how I can check if I have `glBindImageTexture`?

Comment: I just debugged my program with lldb and it says that `glBindImageTexture` throws an invalid address error because the address is a `nullptr` (0x0). Any idea why this function throws such an error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml `glBindImageTexture`is only available in GL versions greater or equal to 4.2. After updating the GL version of my project everyone works fine now.